# WPF Dynamic image generation and printing is not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In an application I'm developing, the user can select a number of items (max. 6) in a datagrid. These items should then be printed in a matrix style on pre-printed forms (see it like CD labels, 6 on a page).

I'm generating these images dynamically containing the selected content from a database. I then put these in a grid so they can be printed on the pre-printed forms.

I have the following code that creates the grid, generates the images from a user control and adds them to the grid and then prints these images.
I'm not following the MVVM pattern for the printing action. I created a reference to my view model in my code-behind.

```
Private Sub PrintButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonPrint.Click

    Dim dlg As New PrintDialog
    dlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = New PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4)
    Dim pageWidth As Double = GetPageWidth(dlg)

    'Since the label is a perfect square: labelWidth = labelHeight
    Dim labelWidthInPx As Integer = Utilities.ConvertMmToPixels(My.Settings.LabelWidthInMm)

    'Set spacing distances in pixels
    Dim horizontalLabelSpacing As Integer = Utilities.ConvertMmToPixels(My.Settings.HorizontalLabelSpacinginMm)
    Dim verticalLabelSpacing As Integer = Utilities.ConvertMmToPixels(My.Settings.VerticalLabelSpacingInMm)
    Dim topMargin As Integer = Utilities.ConvertMmToPixels(My.Settings.TopMarginInMm)
    Dim leftMargin As Integer = Utilities.ConvertMmToPixels(My.Settings.LeftMarginInMm)
    Dim bottomMargin As Integer = Utilities.ConvertMmToPixels(My.Settings.BottomMarginInMm)

    'Create the table/grid
    Dim tbl As New Grid
    If CheckBoxPrintGridLines.IsChecked Then
        tbl.ShowGridLines = True
    Else
        tbl.ShowGridLines = False
    End If

    'Add 3 columns (2 for the labels, 1 for spacing)
    Dim col1 As New ColumnDefinition With {
        .Width = New GridLength(labelWidthInPx, GridUnitType.Pixel)
    }
    Dim col2 As New ColumnDefinition With {
        .Width = New GridLength(horizontalLabelSpacing, GridUnitType.Pixel)
    }
    Dim col3 As New ColumnDefinition With {
        .Width = New GridLength(labelWidthInPx, GridUnitType.Pixel)
    }
    tbl.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1)
    tbl.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2)
    tbl.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col3)

    'Add 5 Rows (3 for labels, 2 for spacing)
    Dim row1 As New RowDefinition With {
        .Height = New GridLength(labelWidthInPx, GridUnitType.Pixel)
    }
    Dim row2 As New RowDefinition With {
        .Height = New GridLength(verticalLabelSpacing, GridUnitType.Pixel)
    }
    Dim row3 As New RowDefinition With {
        .Height = New GridLength(labelWidthInPx, GridUnitType.Pixel)
    }
    Dim row4 As New RowDefinition With {
        .Height = New GridLength(verticalLabelSpacing, GridUnitType.Pixel)
    }
    Dim row5 As New RowDefinition With {
        .Height = New GridLength(labelWidthInPx, GridUnitType.Pixel)
    }

    tbl.RowDefinitions.Add(row1)
    tbl.RowDefinitions.Add(row2)
    tbl.RowDefinitions.Add(row3)
    tbl.RowDefinitions.Add(row4)
    tbl.RowDefinitions.Add(row5)


    'Add label images
    Dim reelData = CType(DataGridReels.ItemsSource, List(Of ReelInfo))
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
    For Each reel In reelData.Where(Function(r) r.IsSelected = True)
        Dim partNumberData = ViewModel.DataService.GetPartNumberDataAsync(reel.PartNumber)
        Dim batchData = ViewModel.DataService.GetBatchDataAsync(reel.PartNumber, reel.HENBatchNumber)

        LabelImageControl.IsPrinting = True
        LabelImageControl.PartNumberData = partNumberData.Result
        LabelImageControl.BatchData = batchData.Result
        LabelImageControl.ReelData = reel
        LabelImageControl.Refresh

        UpdateUI()

        Dim labelImage As New Image
        labelImage = GetImageFromLabel(LabelImageControl)
        labelImage.Width = labelWidthInPx
        labelImage.Height = labelWidthInPx
        Grid.SetRow(labelImage, rowIndex)
        Grid.SetColumn(labelImage, colIndex)
        tbl.Children.Add(labelImage)
        tbl.Refresh

        colIndex += 1
        If colIndex > 1 Then
            colIndex = 0
            rowIndex += 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim iuc As New InlineUIContainer(tbl)
    Dim p As New Paragraph(iuc)

    'Create print dialog
    If dlg.ShowDialog.GetValueOrDefault Then
        'Create a flow document
        Dim doc As New FlowDocument With {
            .Name = "LabelPage",
            .ColumnWidth = pageWidth, 
            .PagePadding = New Thickness(leftMargin, topMargin, 0, bottomMargin)
            }

        doc.Blocks.Add(p)

        'Create IDocumentPagniatorSource from FlowDocument
        Dim idpSource As IDocumentPaginatorSource = doc
        Try
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Wait
            dlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Label Page")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred during printing: " & ex.Message, "Print error")
        Finally
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

When I send the output to the PDF printer I only get one image in the top left corner of the page/grid.
Since the user control (LabelImageControl) is in the XAML, I can see it changing while debugging. So the data is coming into the user control correctly.
When I check the grid with the XML Visualiser I see it has the same number of children as the items I selected in the datagrid.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to get the grid printing correctly?

Comment: As you are only incrementing `colIndex` and `rowIndex` by 1, won't some of the images end up in the "spacing" cells? (If these are very narrow then it's possible you wouldn't see the images). I would still expect to see more than one image if this was happening but it's something to check...

Comment: Genius! That did the trick. I've been looking over this code for so long that I just missed that. Thanks a lot!